# Show that if $p(x)$ is reducible in $F[x]$, then $F[x]/(p(x))$ is not an integral domain.

Tags: ring-theory

So I know that for it to be an integral domain it has to have the following properties:

1. Commutative
2. Has multiplicative identity
3. No Zero-Divisors

and if $p(x)$ is reducible it can be written as $p(x) = (x-a)q(x)$ but I can't seem to link it together to prove that it violates one of the three properties.

Comment: Why should $p(x)$ have a linear factor?

Comment: If $p(x)=q(x)h(x)$, then try showing that $q(x)$ and $h(x)$ are zero divisors by multiplying them together in the $F[x]/(p(x))$ ring.

Comment: @NobleMushtak so if $q(x)h(x) = 0$ then one of them is a zero divisor if they are both non-zero polynomials, but how do I prove that they are equal to zero?

Comment: Well, you know that in $F[x]$, $q(x)h(x)=p(x)$. What is $p(x)$ equal to $F[x]/(p(x))$?

Comment: @NobleMushtak I'm not sure what conclusion to make. Is it equal to zero?

Comment: You can try the contrapositive also by using the characterization of R/A is an integral domain if and only if A is a prime ideal and using the PIDness of $F[x]$ you can conclude that things that are prime are irreducible things.

Comment: As an addendum to the first comment,  $x^4 + 4x^2 + 4  \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ is reducible as $(x^2 + 2)^2$, but it is not divisible by a linear factor, i.e. has no roots in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $R = F[x]$.  The important thing is that $R$ is a **principal ideal domain**: thus every nonzero nonunit factors as a product of irreducible elements.  Every ideal of $R$ is generated by a single element in $R$, and that ideal is a prime ideal if and only if the element generating it is either $0$ or an irreducible element.

If $p$ is reducible, then the ideal $(p)$ generated by $p$ is not a prime ideal.  Hence the quotient ring $F[X]/(p)$ is not an integral domain.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say $p(x)$ is reducible so that $q(x)h(x)=p(x)$ for non-constant polynomials $q(x)$ and $h(x)$.

Now, consider $q(x)h(x)+\langle p(x)\rangle$ in the ring $F[X]/\langle p(x)\rangle$. Normally, $q(x)h(x)=p(x)=p(x)$, so clearly, $q(x)p(x) \in \langle p(x)\rangle$. Therefore:
$$q(x)h(x)+\langle p(x)\rangle=0+\langle p(x)\rangle$$

This means $(q(x)+\langle p(x)\rangle)(h(x)+\langle p(x)\rangle)=0+\langle p(x)\rangle$. Now, we need to prove that $q(x)+\langle p(x)\rangle$ and $h(x)+\langle p(x)\rangle$ are non-zero. Well, what does $q(x)+\langle p(x)\rangle$ being $0$ really mean? It means $q(x) \in \langle p(x)\rangle$, which means $q(x)=p(x)r(x)$ for some polynomial $r(x)$. However, $p(x)=q(x)h(x)$, so we have the following:
$$q(x)=q(x)h(x)r(x)$$
This clearly implies that $h(x)r(x)=1$. However, this can only happen if $h(x)$ is a constant polynomial, which we assumed it wasn't. Therefore, $q(x)+\langle p(x)\rangle$ must be non-zero and $h(x)+\langle p(x)\rangle$ is also non-zero.

Thus, we have found two non-zero elements which, when multiplied, yield zero, which means that the ring $F[X]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ has zero divisors, meaning it is not an integral domain.

Comment: You still need an argument to show that $q(x) + \langle p(x)\rangle$ and $h(x) + \langle p(x)\rangle$ are non-zero in $F[X]/\langle p(x)\rangle$.

Comment: I think you meant $p$ is reducible in the first sentence.

Comment: @Magdiragdag Thank you for the fixes! I kind of wrote this answer in a rush, so I forgot about that.